# If/else in Observable

Tags: java, reactive-programming, observable, reactivex

I´m having some issue to understand how can I refactor this if/else condition inside a loop using Observables.

Here is my code:

```
for (Restrictions restrictions : Restrictions.values()) {
    if (conditionA(restrictions) {
        //Do something A
    } else {
        //Do something B
    }
}
```

I would like to have something like

```
Observable.from(Restrictions.values()).filter(restrictions -> ....)
```

But I don't know how to express the if/else.

Any Suggestions?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
Observable.from(Restrictions.values())
.groupBy(restriction -> conditionA(restriction))})
...
```

Comment: I read the definition of GroupBy but still I cannot see how to do the if/else. In your example where is the conditionB defined?

Comment: And your question where conditionB is defined ? )

Comment: Sorry I mean the DO something A and "Do something B". I´ll play with groupBy thanks